# help with reflections and annotations in java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm having trouble with doubling up on my code for no reason other than my own lack of ability to do it more efficiently...

```
for (Method curr: all){
        if (curr.isAnnotationPresent(anno)){
            if (anno == Pre.class){
                for (String str : curr.getAnnotation(Pre.class).value()){
                    if (str.equals(method.getName()) && curr.getReturnType() == boolean.class && curr.getParameterTypes().length == 0){
                        toRun.add(curr);
                    }
                }
            } if (anno == Post.class) {
                for (String str : curr.getAnnotation(Post.class).value()){
                    if (str.equals(method.getName()) && curr.getReturnType() == boolean.class && curr.getParameterTypes().length == 0){
                        toRun.add(curr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

anno is a parameter - `Class<? extends Annotation>`, and `Pre` and `Post` are my annotations, both have a `value()` which is an array of strings.

Of course, this is all due to the fact that i let Eclipse auto fill code that i don't understand yet.

Comment: What do you want to do if `anno` is neither, and what type is `toRun`?

Comment: Try to eliminate the redundancy (in the conditional expression).

Answer (score 2):

If by 'more efficiently' you mean 'in fewer lines of code', then why not merge the two if statements? The only difference I can see between them is one has `Pre.class` where the other has `Post.class`, and you already have that class reference conveniently in the anno var:

```
for (Method curr : all) {
    if (curr.isAnnotationPresent(anno)) {
        if (anno == Pre.class || anno == Post.class){
            for (String str : curr.getAnnotation(anno).value()){
                if (str.equals(method.getName()) && curr.getReturnType() == boolean.class && curr.getParameterTypes().length == 0){
                    toRun.add(curr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Further to that, there's no point in doing the outer for loop if `anno` is neither `Pre.class` nor `Post.class`, so you should do that check outside (this saves iterating over the methods if it's called with an annotation you don't want). You can also move the checks for the returnType and parameter length outside the inner for loop (this saves repeating them for each of the values, and saves iterating at all if they're not true).

```
 if (anno == Pre.class || anno == Post.class){
    for (Method curr : all) {
        if (curr.isAnnotationPresent(anno) && curr.getReturnType() == boolean.class && curr.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            for (String str : curr.getAnnotation(anno).value()){
                if (str.equals(method.getName())) {
                    toRun.add(curr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `curr.getAnnotation(anno).value()` can't compile. since it doesn't know what annotation is `anno` then it can't know that it has a `value()`. is I was to cast it using (Pre)(curr...) then it would work, but that doesn't really advance me anywhere.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I guess you'd have to do something like this then: `final String[] values = anno == Pre.class? curr.getAnnotation(Pre.class).value() : curr.getAnnotation(Post.class).value();`, then iterate over that. Ugly, but can't see any other way as you can't do any kind of inheritance with annotations :/

Comment: What might be possible is making a base annotation that both `Pre` and `Post` will inherit from. lets call it `BaseAnno`. then using `anno instanceof BaseAnno` and casting later.